# Video loop em html5 fazendo re-downloads infinitos. Estourando consumo de banda

Tags: javascript, html5, vídeo

Estou utilizando um vídeo como background da área superior do site.

Idêntico a [este site](http://raincake.com.br/), que utiliza um `<iframe>` apontando para um vídeo no YouTube.

O grande problema que eu notei em todos os sites que usam vídeo assim é que o vídeo não armazena em cache e fica fazendo infinitos re-downloads. 
Estamos tendo uma dor de cabeça com isso, pois usuários que possuem franquia limite de banda estão sendo prejudicados por downloads desnecessários.

Só pra ter uma noção um site com esse recurso de vídeo aberto por algumas horas consumiu 4GB de download.

O que posso fazer para o vídeo carregar apenas uma vez, armazenar no cache e ficar repetindo sem essa necessidade de re-download?

Answer (score 3):

Várias abordagens estão à sua disposição. Escolha uma (ou várias) delas.

- Reduza o *bitrate* do vídeo em *background*. Utilize uma *tiling mask* sobre o vídeo para reduzir o efeito de granulação.
- Execute o vídeo por 5 minutos, e depois destrua o elemento e substitua por uma imagem estática.
- Converta o video para um formato que possa sofrer *caching* local (mp4, por exemplo) ao invés de uma chamada ao YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar o "re-download infinito" você pode tentar baixar o vídeo e disponibilizar ele no seu servidor ao invés de usar o tradicional iframe com o conteúdo do youtube.

Caso for tentar fazer isso, indico você dar uma olhada no plugin [jQuery VIDE](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/), que já faz vários tratamentos tais como verificar exibição em dispositivos móveis que não dão suporte à função e substituir por banners referentes ao vídeo, dentre outras funcionalidades.

https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide